# How to use While Loop to execute Airflow operator

Tags: python, airflow

Requirement: Run SQL query for each date using while loop. For example: Start date selected as 25 Aug and end date as 28 Aug. Then BigQueryOperator first run for 25 Aug, then 26 Aug and so on till we reach to 28 Aug.

Issue: In below DAG, it only execute query for start date and then complete job. It does not even execute/iterate BigQueryOperator to next date and so on.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 31),
    'email': ['xyz@xyz.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
    'depends_on_past': False
}

dag = DAG('his_temp',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None)

date1 = datetime.date(2018, 8, 25)
date2 = datetime.date(2018, 8, 28)
day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

while date1 <= date2:
    parameter = {
        'dataset': "projectname.finance",
        'historical_date': date1.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    }


    sqlpartition = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='execute_sqlpartition',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    allow_large_results=True,
    bql="sqlqueries/sqlpartition.sql",
    destination_dataset_table=parameter.get('dataset') + "." + "date_partition_" + parameter.get('historical_date'),
    params=parameter,
    bigquery_conn_id='bigquery',
    dag=dag)

    print "data loaded for "+ parameter.get('historical_date')

    date1 = date1 + day
```

Comment: I think your task_id needs to be unique. Iterate a number variable and do something along the lines of `task_id='execute_sqlpartition_{}'.format(mynumber)`

Comment: Bah. Already answered in another comment I see....

Answer (score 4):

You can add a self triggering operator at the end of your dependancies. Something like the following:

```
def trigger_check(context, dag_run_obj):
    if date1 <= date2:
        return dag_run_obj
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="test_trigger_dagrun",
    trigger_dag_id="his_temp",
    python_callable=trigger_check,
    ... more arguments
)
op1 >> op2 >> ... >> trigger
```

Once you trigger it a first time, it will loop through dates until it reaches the date2 threshold. You'll have to be more careful with updating the date by making that an ordered PythonOperator or something like that

Comment: This worked great, thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The entire concept of Airflow scheduler is that it will schedule the tasks and you just need to configure it properly. No wonder it is running once as start date mentioned as the dag start date will be picked and as there is no daily task is scheduled it will run once and stop. You have to configure at the dag level rather than the operator level.

Refer docs for correct timing and scheduling interval [Scheduler docs](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs)

Comment: thanks for reply but i do not want to schedule this particular DAG and that is reason schedule_interval is set to None. I just wanted to iterate task from start date till end date. For example: there is partition table schema.xyz_20180825. First i wanted to run task to select this partition table and update schema.table_20180825 then in next iteration it will select schema.xyz_20180826 and update schema.table_20180826 and so on.

Comment: Okay great. Now I got it. The issue is that you are creating a task with the same name and attaching to the same dag which Airflow considers that it has already processed. The workaround to not schedule the dag is change the name of the task_id and call sqlpartition.run() explicitly at the end of declaration of the task. Hopefully it should solve the problem.

Comment: Issue with appending task(for example: task_id='execute_sqlpartition_'+parameter.get('historical_date'), ) this will create parallel task that may blowdown sql database if i set start date and end date with 1 year range. In that case , 365 airflow task will run at same time :). I just want airflow to run just one task at a time for one date, once finish then use same task and run for next date..etc.

Comment: It won't create parallel task just like that. It will be created in your while loop. Only one task will be executed at one time. It is similar to a function call but creating a task. Hope that makes sense. Your question seems to be a good candidate for scheduler to run the task.

Comment: @mad_ thanks a lot for explaining the part "you are creating a task with the same name and attaching to the same dag which Airflow considers that it has already processed. " as i am looking for exactly to achieve this kind of result, I worry my 
 operator (which is acting like a fan out operator), inside a loop,  and it should be executed only once for the whole loop.. now i am less concerned.